# Where to put definition file to be accessible in multiple apps in NRWL

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl

I'm using NRWL to manage my projects. Currently, I have two projects that use custom definition files for typescript. Say, I have **json-typings.d.ts** and **custom.d.ts**.

Example the **json-typings.d.ts** definition file is this:

```
 declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Source: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

So whenever I run app-project-1 or app-project-2 I need to place those two custom definition files in each, making duplicates; or worst just move them whenever I serve a project. I even tried placing them in libs or apps folder but still wouldn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: A custom definition, like what? Typescript definitions or Environments? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @AkshayRajput. it's typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root of the workspace, you will be able to see a file `tsconfig.json` where all definitions are defined, and if you open an app inside the workspace, there is a file `tsconfig.app.json`, if you open the code for `tsconfig.app.json` its first line is it extends `tsconfig.json`, you can do something like that, `tsconfig.json` is common to complete app and `tsconfig.app.json` is app specific

Comment: Cool! Thanks @Akshay. I included the files in tsconfig.json and it worked! So I did it like this, for reference to everybody:

in tsconfig.json
{
 "compilerOptions": {...},
 "files": [
     "libs/types/json-typings.d.ts",
     "libs/types/custom.d.ts"
   ]
}

Comment: It does not work for me. All the child tsconfigs override the `files` array now.